# how to find issues in slow load MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My page loading was too slow.  so I recorded slow queries with turning on slow query log. 
it shows me only one query which taking 10seconds..and I see nothing wrong in that query. 
can anyone suggest me what to do? 
as everything written in query is needed and up to the point as far as I know.

I am just posting SQL query here. but PHP code is somewhat different with many 'where conditions' let me know if that is a need too.

please see if anyone can help

QUERY LOG- >

# Query_time: 10.729023  Lock_time: 0.302145  Rows_sent: 20  Rows_examined: 162426
   # Rows_affected: 0

SQL QUERY - >

```
SELECT
po.type,
po.ecom_order_id,
po.ecom_order_num,
po.seller_id,
po.customer_id,
po.store_id,
po.product_id,
p.product_name,
p.product_sku,
p.mtn_code,
p.cost_price,
po.size_id,
po.color_id,
c.color_name,
po.quantity,
po.price,
u.first_name,
u.last_name,
ua.first_name as modi_fname,
ua.last_name as modi_lname,
po.dfrom_store,
st.store_name as dfrom_storename,
date_format(po.created_on, " % d -% b -% Y") cret_on,
date_format(po.modified_on, " % d -% b -% Y") modi_on,
date_format(po.order_date, " % d -% b -% Y") order_date,
date_format(po.ship_date, " % d -% b -% Y") ship_date,
date_format(po.payment_date, " % d -% b -% Y") payment_date,
date_format(po.delivered_date, " % d -% b -% Y") delivered_date,
date_format(po.manifest_date, " % d -% b -% Y") manifest_date,
cu.customer_name,
cu.mobile,
cu.address,
cu.city,
cu.email_id,
ctp.display_label as size,
es.seller_name,
po.tracking_no,
po.logistics_amt,
po.payment_status,
ctpl.display_label as order_status,
po.status,
po.order_note,
es.image as seller_logo,
es.seller_margin,
es.other_fee,
po.seller_margin as ecom_seller_margin,
po.seller_other_fee,
po.prod_cost_price,
po.is_approved,
ub.first_name as ap_fname,
ub.last_name as ap_lname,
po.payment_received,
po.logistics_provider,
po.gst_tax,
po.gross_margin,
po.gross_percent 
FROM
(
    ecom_orders po
)
LEFT JOIN
    e_sellers es 
    ON es.seller_id = po.seller_id 
LEFT JOIN
    product p 
    ON p.id = po.product_id 
LEFT JOIN
    colors c 
    ON c.color_id = po.color_id 
LEFT JOIN
    master_config ctp 
    ON ctp.value2 = po.size_id 
    AND ctp.key = 'product_size' 
LEFT JOIN
    master_config ctpl 
    ON ctpl.value2 = po.status 
    AND ctpl.key = 'ecom_order_status' 
LEFT JOIN
    user u 
    ON u.userid = po.created_by 
LEFT JOIN
    user ua 
    ON ua.userid = po.modified_by 
LEFT JOIN
    user ub 
    ON ub.userid = po.approved_by 
LEFT JOIN
    customers cu 
    ON cu.cust_id = po.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN
    stores st 
    ON st.id = po.dfrom_store 
WHERE
`po`.`is_deleted` = 'N' 
AND `po`.`store_id` = '2' 
ORDER BY
po.modified_on desc LIMIT 20;
```

The EXPLAIN:

[image]

UPDATE -->
created index. now row counts are less ..

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ecom
```

ON ecom_orders (store_id,is_deleted,modified_on);

if i index key and value2 , should i use composite index or index them separately ? key field contains text and value2 contains int, so i have to use FULLTEXT index or not ?

also i found this written somewhere->

> Indexes get updated on any modifications to the data, so yes, adding
>   more indexes can lead to degradation in INSERT/UPDATE performance. If
>   indexes didn't get updated, you would get different information
>   depending on whether the optimizer decided to run your query on an
>   index or the raw table

is it so ?

the table you people suggested me to index is very active and daily 1000+ rows are being insert and update in this ?
how can i avoid situation of degradation of performance.

UPDATE 2->
i have updated indexes.. and it loads really fast.. but in timelog there is another query of the same page shows delay. 
I checked it with EXPLAIN - it is null in reference but showing index value i set above. 
why it is taking null ? how to solve this ?

UPDATE 3->

on a online query optimisation website.. i got this result..

```
ALTER TABLE `colors` ADD INDEX `colors_idx_id` (`color_id`);
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD INDEX `customers_idx_id` (`cust_id`);
ALTER TABLE `e_sellers` ADD INDEX `e_sellers_idx_id` (`seller_id`);
ALTER TABLE `ecom_orders` ADD INDEX `ecom_orders_idx_deleted_on` (`is_deleted`,`modified_on`);
ALTER TABLE `ecom_orders` ADD INDEX `ecom_orders_idx_on` (`modified_on`);
ALTER TABLE `master_config` ADD INDEX `master_config_idx_key_value2` (`key`,`value2`);
ALTER TABLE `product` ADD INDEX `product_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `stores` ADD INDEX `stores_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD INDEX `user_idx_userid` (`userid`);
```

is this good ?? can i use this now on the earlier made index ? or first i should drop previously created index??

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN ..` statement on your query and see if it is using any index or not. Do you have any index defined on the table(s) or not ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it gives this- > https://imgur.com/GtsCaz5

when i run explain on this statement

Comment: i dont know .. but i think it should display index instead of all in the first column .. 
this is what you mean by index ?? please help how do i index it ?

Comment: Based on the `EXPLAIN` result, create a Composite index (is_deleted,store_id,modified_on) on your `ecom_orders` table

Comment: Also, add a composite index (value2,key) in the master_config table.

Comment: how to do that ? i am new to this .. and please also explain me how you find out this with explain results... i want to learn

Comment: i have used the same table data to many places.. it wont effect others ? right ?

Comment: Index does not change data; it can only speed up selecting data, if query and index are defined properly.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya   should i use FULLTEXT index on key ?? key field contains text

Answer (score 1):

Based on the observation on the EXPLAIN OUTPUT:

- ctp doesnt have index
- ctpl doesnt have index
- type "ALL"  is equivalent to full scan, therefore slow fetching of records.
- your table `po`  doesnt have index, you were performing condition on [WHERE], the explain should be showing that.  No index, means slow querying.  Add indexes on   ***is_deleted***  and  ***store_id***

```
`po`.`is_deleted` = 'N' 
AND `po`.`store_id` = '2'
```

- dont forget to add index on ***modified_on***  column

**ROWS** represents the cardinality of from the index generated. Smaller the number the better

Comment: The force is strong in this one.

Comment: It works like this ? - >
CREATE INDEX ecom_orders_ind ON ecom_orders(is_deleted , store_id, modified_on);

this is how i can create index ? and how about creating index on all the fields in all tables of database ? if it speeds up .. creating index to all fields would be a good practice ??

Comment: @AnshM  when creating indexes it could be single column or multiple column. Consider index as a dictionary of your table.  
Too much indexes on tables also makes the query slow, it's double edge. When you index, apply index wisely.

Comment: ok got it ..  thanks :) . so if i write create index index-name ON tablename(field1,field5,field6); and run it .. will it make query fast ?? thats it ??   i need to run this one time in phpmyadmin ?? or do i have to insert this code in my model_file.php with eachrun ?

Comment: it's only declared once. No need to create index each run.

Comment: done ...i run this query in phpmyadmin ->
 CREATE INDEX idx_ecom
ON ecom_orders (is_deleted, store_id, modified_on);

but it is still slow. .am i doing it right ?? do i have to modify my sql query ?

Comment: also please tell me -- -- that what i did is correct ? or i have to index them separately with separate index names - like - 
CREATE INDEX idx_isdeleted
ON ecom_orders(is_deleted);    

CREATE INDEX idx_storeid
ON ecom_orders(store_id);   and so on